# What page is this PHP code referring to? (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Working on http://mbccs5.wpstagecoach.com/ right now. About half-way down the page there are two images (99% uptime..., 50% savings...). They're being called with the php code below. Can someone please help me figure out where these links/images/headers are located so that I can update them? Is there a trick to knowing what page get_page('#') is referring to?

Thanks so much :)

```html
<div id="I love _wrapper">
    <div id="service">
        <?php
            $page_mid = get_page('190');
            echo $page_mid->post_content;        
        ?>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page

Comment: Great point! I was hoping pointing him to the documentation would help him see that too. But I probably should have just mentioned it in the answer.

Comment: hah... yeah apparently she* couldn't figure it out from that page. Darn newbie. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually getting the page with ID 190 and then echo'ing the page contents. The 2 images you are looking for are probably inside page 190. You can find out where the images are located by visiting the website and copying the image address.

If you have a hard time finding the page with ID 190 there is a little trick, just click on edit for any random page, then changing the `post=NUM` to the page_id you want to edit. Something among the lines of:

```
mywebsite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=14&action=edit
```

edit that to:

```
mywebsite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=190&action=edit
```

Comment: THIS IS BRILLIANT. I'm so freakin' happy with you right now. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: You can thank me by accepting this answer (the green arrow next to the counter) ;)

Comment: Like, seriously, anyone who ever uses wordpress should be made aware of this trick like right now. Brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

`get_page(id)` gets a specific page from the WordPress DB. You just pass in the page ID. So this is grabbing whatever the 190th page in your pages table is and displaying its content.  More here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page

Comment: This function is deprecated...you should use [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) instead.

Comment: Thank ya! Funny enough, I'd already looked at that page. Terwanerik's comment must have been psychic for knowing exactly what I needed. :) Thanks for commenting, though.